# query one-to-many tables and return any existing data if not exist by id

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, inner-join

I have 2 database tables:

```
Doctors: ID
Doctors_Sub: Doctors.ID, LanguageID, Name
```

I want to fetch a specific doctor based on `ID`, and fetch its sub-data by `LanguageID`, But if that `LanguageID` is not present, i want to get anything else.

So, if Doctor 1 has data for Lanuage 1 only. If i query Doctor 1 for Language 2, I want to return language 1.

This is where i got so far:

```
select dr.id, df.name 
from doctors dr
left outer join doctors_defs df ON dr.id = df.doctor_id
where dr.id = drid and (df.lid = lid or lid > 0)
limit 1
```

This returns any of the language randomly. I want it to first look if the language I'm requesting exists, or else return any other

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN with the `doctor_defs` table twice, once to get the name with the specified language, and a second time using a subquery that picks one of the names for each doctor. Then use `IFNULL` to prefer the specified language.

```
SELECT dr.id, IFNULL(df1.name, df2.name) AS name
FROM doctors AS dr
LEFT JOIN doctor_defs AS df1 on dr.id = df1.doctor_id AND df1.languageID = @lid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT doctor_id, MAX(name) AS name
           FROM doctor_defs
           GROUP BY doctor_id) AS df2 ON dr.id = df2.doctor_id
```